# pyparsing scanString with spaces not able to parse

Tags: python, regex, pyparsing

I am using below regex expression (with pyparsing), which doesn't give any output. Any idea what I am doing wrong here.

```
>>> pat = pp.Regex('\s+\w+')    
>>> x = " ***    abc   xyz   pqr"
>>> for result, start, end in pat.scanString(x):
    print result, start, end
```

if `\s` is removed. We get the data

```
>>> pat = pp.Regex('\w+')   
>>> x = " ***    abc   xyz   pqr"
>>> for result, start, end in pat.scanString(x):
    print result, start, end

['abc'] 8 11
['xyz'] 14 17
['pqr'] 20 23
```

Comment: Do you actually *want* the leading spaces in your data? Or did you think you had to include the `\s+` in your pattern because regex?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.ptmcg.com/geo/python/howtousepyparsing.html), whitespaces are skipped by default in pyparsing.

> During the matching process, whitespace between tokens is skipped by default (although this can be changed).

But [Regex](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.Regex-class.html) class inherits from [ParserElement](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html) which has a leaveWhitespace() method.

> leaveWhitespace(self)     source code
>
> Disables the skipping of whitespace before matching the characters in
>   the ParserElement's defined pattern. This is normally only used
>   internally by the pyparsing module, but may be needed in some
>   whitespace-sensitive grammars.

So this code works :

```
>>> pat = pp.Regex('\s+\w+')
>>> pat.leaveWhitespace()
>>> x = " ***    abc   xyz   pqr"
>>> for result, start, end in pat.scanString(x):
        print result, start, end

['    abc'] 4 11
['   xyz'] 11 17
['   pqr'] 17 23
```